# The property of normed space, , closed subspace, and distance.

Tags: normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

$X$ : normed space on $K=\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ with norm $\|\cdot \|$

$L \subsetneq X$ : closed linear subspace.

$a\in X\setminus L.$

Then, define the distance between $a$ and $L$ by $d(a,L)=\inf\{ \|a-l\| \mid l\in L\}.$

Prove $d(a,L)=\inf\{  \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}.$

---

$\leqq$ is obvious since $\{ \|a-l\| \mid l\in L\}\supset \{ \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}$, so I have to show $d(a,L)\geqq\inf\{  \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}$.

Pick $l\in L$ arbitrarily.

It suffices to show $\|a-l\| \geqq \inf\{  \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}.$

If $l\neq 0$, then $\|a-l \|\geqq \inf\{  \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}$ is obvious.

If $l=0,$ how should I do ?

If $l=0,$ then $\|a-l\|=\|a\|$ and I cannot show $\|a\|\geqq\inf\{  \|a-l\| \mid l\in L,\ l\neq 0 \}$.

This seems not so difficult but I'm in trouble with showing this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix any $b \neq 0$ in $L$ and note that $\|a-\frac  1n  b\| \geq \inf \{\|a-l\|: l \in L, l\neq 0\}$. Take limit as $n \to \infty$. to see that $\|a\| \geq \inf \{\|a-l\|: l \in L, l\neq 0\}$.